# Enterprise to Enterprise App Distribution with Apple

Tags: ios, certificate, enterprise-distribution

Company A builds an app and sells it to company B. Company B distributes the app to its employees.

My understanding is that company B will need to have an Apple Enterprise account in order to install and distribute the app to their employees. Company A can not distribute the app to company B using their (company A) enterprise account.

Is this correct?

Second Question:
During Demo and Testing what is the best (and legal) approach for Company A to install/distribute the app to company B and other random companies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Company B will need the Enterprise account, for testing you could use AdHoc and include some of the UDID of the devices you want to test on.

Or you could just use the InHouse profile so all device can install the app. Doing this you might want to build some kind of restriction in your app, like to test if the version is still active.

Comment: Is it legal to distribute the app to a different company using AdHoc and Enterprise Account? Can company A use their developer account and Test Flight to distribute to company B for testing purposes. i.e. Company A can add the uuid's of company B devices?

Comment: AdHoc, yes this is legal. But If company A holds the enterprise license then you can not officially distribute to company B. But if company B hold the account then it is free to distribute it to it employees.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can upload the application signature to the distribution platform and he can download it for "B"